# Regex with conditions

Tags: regex, python-3.x

I have two lists of words, and i'm building a regex to parse a list of strings.

```
sub = []
for pos,line in enumerate(lines):
  for word in wordsFromList1:
    regex = r".?" + re.escape(word) + r"(.*?)\."
    try:
      found = re.finditer(regex, line, re.IGNORECASE)
      for matchNum, match in enumerate(found):
        for groupNum in range(0, len(match.groups())):
          groupNum = groupNum + 1
          sub.append(word + ' ->' + match.group(groupNum))
    except AttributeError:
      found = 'error'
```

Right now i'm cycling through the first list, finding a term and capturing everything after that until a period shows up. But, sometimes i would prefer to cut that capture short IF a word from wordsFromList2 comes before the period. How would i change the expression (while nesting another loop for that list) in order to make that happen?

Thanks!

Comment: could you please post the sample list of string , and expected output as well , as this is an incomplete question , most probably will get down voted too

Comment: Let's say: "it's very cold outside so you might aswell get a coat." If word = coat, then it grabs 'outside so you might aswell get a coat"

I want to also run at the same time a list of "end words", which one of them could be 'get', so it would grab 'outside so you might aswell'. If no word on the list of the "end words" matches before the period, it ends on the period.

Basically, something like stopping on \. OR endword.

Comment: You are roaming into space then , only if you place some input sample list and expected out , people would be helping you here , Lot of sentence with no meaning will end up in Cold , so get a coat before you go outside .